# URI Error running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri

I am attempting to setup the rails server from the following github project:
https://github.com/Bernie-2016/fieldthebern-api

I know that people were recently able to pull this project and have the server up and running. However, when I attempt after bundle install when I type rake db:setup I obtain the following error:

```
ground_game_dev already exists
D, [2018-01-17T15:49:44.313281 #7026] DEBUG -- : ** [Raven] Event not sent due to excluded environment: development
```

`rake aborted!`

```
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?):
```

I was hoping for some insight into this, I can't figure out a solution

Comment: Try `rake db:drop db:setup`

Comment: No dice, I get the exact same error.

Comment: Can you make sure if `rake db:drop` worked, can you see if that deleted the database `ground_game_dev` and try after that

Comment: I used db:drop and checked with psql and found that I had deleted the ground_game_dev database. After doing this I found that running rake db:setup still returned the error 
Event not sent due to excluded environment: development

rake aborted!

URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?):

Comment: I found out that moving the .env.sample file to .env was able to fix this problem. I am not completely sure why though.